# How to store user specific files in blob containers

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are developing an application where a user can login and save the files. He can also share some files with other users to whom he want to provide access. Now the issue is how to manage blob level access specific to a user.

Let me explain with a simple scenario :

There are 2 users A & B login to our application. I am creating a container for each user to store user's files. Now User A want to share some files with User B. I can do it with an SAS token but the issue is that if User C gets this URL, he can also see the content.

Please let know the best way to handle such scenario.

Comment: Are the users A & B in your application tied to Azure AD?

Comment: Yes.users A & B  tied to Azure AD

Comment: @Sachan were the below answers helpful for you ? Please mark as answer the answer that helped you in your issue. If not, please add additional questions so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

If both users A and B are tied to Azure AD, then you can possibly use [`Azure AD based authentication for Azure Blob and Queue Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

I have not tried it myself but the way I understand it is that you assign a `Blob Reader Role` to a user and grant them permission on a blob container and that user will be able to read blobs from that container.

If I understand correctly you only want User A to share certain blobs with User B. In that scenario, you can create another blob container where User A will copy the files she/he wants to share with User B and then grant access to User B on that container (assuming User B has a Blob Reader role).

Comment: Currently, the Azure AD permission can only be granted in account level or container level. Not sure if @sachan needs to grant the permission in blob level.

Comment: That's correct. This is why I suggested that a new container be created by User A, copy the necessary blobs there and then grant User B access to this new container.

Comment: @zhaoxing: I need access at blob level.if this is possible so when any user want to share any blob to other user, this way user can get access easily.

Comment: Or tell me best approach..do I will create one container for each user where he can upload his files..one he want to share any file to other user I will create another container and move the file there and provide other user access to new container. In this approach I have to create container for   each share ..I don't think it's very scalable solution which will be perfect for user count more than lacs

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution for the described scenario is use **AAD/Rbac** to specify the access permissions to only user A and B.

**SAS** unfortunately are not user specific, meaning, if anyone is able to get hold of it, they can re-use it as long as it has not already expired.The only layer that could be added for additional security is: **Allowed IP addresses** to restrict access to only user B.